# How to use html from one html page to other html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `popup` bootstrap code in html file and i want to use in another html file.I have created a button in html file and i want to cal `model` which is in another html file.How can i do this??

**A.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 
<div class="row">    
<div class="col-xs-12"> <button type="button" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-success" style="width:200px;font-size:30px; transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform-origin: right, top;
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform-origin:left, top;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform-origin:left,center;
position: fixed; bottom:30%; right: -73px;
color:white;" class="btn btn-success">Order</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Get the modal
   var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
  // Get the button that opens the modal
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close2")[0];
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}
 // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";   
}
 // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
 window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
    </script>
```

**B.HTML**

```
<html>
<head></head>
 <body>
 <!-- The Modal -->
 <div id="myModal" class="modal2">
 <!-- Modal content -->
 <div class="modal-content2">
  <div class="modal-header">
  <span class="close2">Ã—</span>
  <h2>Order Services</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body2">
  </div>
 <!-- <div class="modal-footer">
  <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
 </div> -->
 </div>
 </div> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

I want to use `B.HTML` from `A.HTML` .How can i accomplish this?

Comment: So why can't you just move the modal into A.html?

Comment: I can't move because if i move this model into my html then this model create problem with another model and design so that's why

Comment: Have you tried only using 1 modal for the entire thing, but Ajax contents into it?

Comment: Actually i have two models for popup and also have div using bootstrap if i use this model in my `A.HTML` then it will not work.If model work then div not works if div works then model not popup.This is the main reason i can't put my model code in same file

Comment: It's hard to see what's going wrong without seeing the site. Because I mainly use one modal which then Ajax's data into it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery or
you cant create your modal as string that contain htmls code in it
for example

```
var = '<div class="model">...</div>'
```

and then set this script in js file and then import it in any file you want to use modal
at the end you can append it into your body or remove it

you can see this link
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal

Comment: sorry i can't understand your method

Comment: i have add some example to post

Comment: you have not understand my problem.I have div model in `B.HTML` and i want to call this model in `A.HTML`. But you provide me example which place in the same file.I already know about it

Comment: i want to use.but how?

Answer (score 0):

Use this script on A.html file

```
$(document).load( "B.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Comment: i want to call model from another html file.

Comment: Thanks for response. But actually I'm new to jquery and i don't know how to move next.If you tell me how can i call this `mymodel` which is in `B.HTML` then i m very thankful to you.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code inside **A.html** .

```
<div id="myModalContainer"></div>

$(document).ready(
   function() {
      $( "#myModalContainer" ).load( "B.html #myModal" );       
   }
);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129728/discussion-on-answer-by-mmuzahid-how-to-use-html-from-one-html-page-to-other-htm).